# What is the Bible and Christian view on Astrology?

Tags: biblical-basis, mosaic-law, divination

Being on this site has given me an opportunity to reflect and investigate more my beliefs and gain a greater understanding of the beliefs of other Christians. I was raised being taught that [astrology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrology) was a pagan practice that went against Christian beliefs. Is that a view that is widely held by other Christians?

I've heard counter views that astrology is another way in which God speaks to man, while others say there is no validity to it at all, and it is just a harmless form of amusement.

Is there a Biblical point of view on astrology?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the Bible speaks strongly against the pagan practice of Astrology, which was recognized as divination and associated with magic and sorcery.  Divination is defined as "the practice of attempting to foretell future events or discover hidden knowledge by occult or supernatural means", which would certainly include Astrology.

A number of scriptures associate astrology with pagan magic arts:

- [Isaiah 47:13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2047:13&version=NIV): Let your astrologers come forward, those stargazers who make predictions month by month
- [Daniel 2:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%202&version=NIV): So the king summoned the magicians, enchanters, sorcerers and astrologers to tell him what he had dreamed.
- [Daniel 2:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%202&version=NIV): The astrologers answered the king, “There is no one on earth who can do what the king asks! No king, however great and mighty, has ever asked such a thing of any magician or enchanter or astrologer.

[Leviticus 19:26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2019&version=NIV) forbids divination:

> Do not practice divination or seek omens.

as does and [Deuteronomy 18:14](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2018&version=NIV)

> The nations you will dispossess listen to those who practice sorcery or divination. But as for you, the LORD your God has not permitted you to do so

and numerous other scriptures:

- [Genesis 44:5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2044&version=NIV): Isn’t this the cup my master drinks from and also uses for divination? This is a wicked thing you have done.
- [Deuteronomy 18:10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy%2018&version=NIV): Let no one be found among you who sacrifices their son or daughter in the fire, who practices divination or sorcery, interprets omens, engages in witchcraft,
- [Joshua 13:22](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joshua%2013&version=NIV): In addition to those slain in battle, the Israelites had put to the sword Balaam son of Beor, who practiced divination.
- [1 Samuel 15:23](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%2015&version=NIV): For rebellion is like the sin of divination, and arrogance like the evil of idolatry. Because you have rejected the word of the LORD, he has rejected you as king.”
- [2 Kings 17:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%2017&version=NIV): They sacrificed their sons and daughters in the fire. They practiced divination and sought omens and sold themselves to do evil in the eyes of the LORD, arousing his anger.
- [2 Kings 21:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%2021&version=NIV): He sacrificed his own son in the fire, practiced divination, sought omens, and consulted mediums and spiritists. He did much evil in the eyes of the LORD, arousing his anger.
- [2 Chronicles 33:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Chronicles%2033&version=NIV): He sacrificed his children in the fire in the Valley of Ben Hinnom, practiced divination and witchcraft, sought omens, and consulted mediums and spiritists. He did much evil in the eyes of the LORD, arousing his anger.
- [Isaiah 2:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%202&version=NIV): They are full of superstitions from the East; they practice divination like the Philistines and embrace pagan customs.
- [Jeremiah 14:14](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%2014&version=NIV): Then the LORD said to me, “The prophets are prophesying lies in my name. I have not sent them or appointed them or spoken to them. They are prophesying to you false visions, divinations, idolatries and the delusions of their own minds.
- [Ezekiel 12:24](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel%2012&version=NIV): For there will be no more false visions or flattering divinations among the people of Israel.
- [Ezekiel 13:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel%2013&version=NIV): Their visions are false and their divinations a lie. Even though the LORD has not sent them, they say, “The LORD declares,” and expect him to fulfill their words.

So if you accept that Astrology is a subset of divination, it seems clearly abhorrent to God.  Given the ensnaring nature of the occult, I would be engaging the "flee from all appearance" tactic with Astrology.

Answer (score 1):

While Software Monkey has lots of references to the old testament, the new testament tells the story of Jesus Christ, who was foreseen by "Three Kings", or "(Three) Wise Men from the East" who read the sky and observed the comet. [Matthew 2:1–12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%202:1%E2%80%9312)

So this is a prove that astrology works, and that it is in the spirit of the Christian God.

Since the old Testament is of minor importance for the Christians, and the only important source for the Jews ...

Comment: The Magi observed a prophesied sign of Christ's birth: A new start appearing. They did not use the movement of the starts and planets to predict the future. I think that is a big difference, but I appreciate the point of view.

Comment: @Jim: Interesting observation.  Where is the prophecy that Christ's birth will be heralded by a new star recorded?

Comment: Well - they interpreted some facts out of the observation of stars, which don't fit into modern science. I don't know how long they travelled to reach Bethlehem, but I guess it was more than a single day, but weeks or months. Due to the rotation of earth, a comet is not at a fixed position on the sky, so you can't just travel in that direction, and look, what you find.

Comment: One story about Magi seeing star and following it does not mean that it is okay to predict the future based on the movements of stars and planets, especially given the number of references in the old testament against that kind of thing. All we know from this is that wise men, saw a star, took it to mean that some important person had been born and followed it.

Answer (score 1):

The Bible is only against going to other astrologers, it never says Jews can't practice astrology. Reading the scriptures one can see its all about control, the where is almost as important as the what. Jews can only offer sacrifice in one place the holy temple in Jerusalem, all other locations are not permitted or acceptable

---

(merged w/ deleted answer)

Take a look the long list of scriptures

> Genesis 44:5: Isn’t this the cup my master drinks from and also uses for divination? This is a wicked thing you have done.

*Divination is not condemned here, but rather the discussion is about misuse of property belonging to the master*.

> Deuteronomy 18:10: Let no one be found among you who sacrifices their son or daughter in the fire, who practices divination or sorcery, interprets omens, engages in witchcraft,

*Reading the scripture in context shows this scripture is concerned with works that promote or  acknowledge other gods other than YHWY*.

> Joshua 13:22: In addition to those slain in battle, the Israelites had put to the sword Balaam son of Beor, who practiced divination.

*This scripture only notes that Balaam practices divination it never says it was bad.*

> 1 Samuel 15:23: For rebellion is like the sin of divination, and arrogance like the evil of idolatry. Because you have rejected the word of the LORD, he has rejected you as king.”

*Another example where the practice is wrong because it is to another God*.

> 2 Kings 17:17: They sacrificed their sons and daughters in the fire. They practiced divination and sought omens and sold themselves to do evil in the eyes of the LORD, arousing his anger.
>
> 2 Kings 21:6: He sacrificed his own son in the fire, practiced divination, sought omens, and consulted mediums and spiritists. He did much evil in the eyes of the LORD, arousing his anger.
>
> 2 Chronicles 33:6: He sacrificed his children in the fire in the Valley of Ben Hinnom, practiced 
>   divination and witchcraft, sought omens, and consulted mediums and spiritists. He did much evil in the eyes of the LORD, arousing his anger.
>
> Isaiah 2:6: They are full of superstitions from the East; they practice divination like the Philistines and embrace pagan customs.

*And yet we have the quandry where Jesus accepts the magi from the East. THey are accepted because they acknowledge the majesty of Jesus. If they had directed their worship or respect in another direction the commentary would be different.*

> Jeremiah 14:14: Then the LORD said to me, “The prophets are prophesying lies in my name. I have not sent them or appointed them or spoken to them. They are prophesying to you false visions, divinations, idolatries and the delusions of their own minds.

**This scripture only condemns the others because they are in competition with the establishment. It also condemns visions from the false prophets and other worshippers. It does not condemn visiions from Jeremiah.
**

> Ezekiel 12:24: For there will be no more false visions or flattering divinations among the people of Israel.
>
> Ezekiel 13:6: Their visions are false and their divinations a lie. Even though the LORD has not sent them, they say, “The LORD declares,” and expect him to fulfill their words.

*This scripture is an example that their failings are because they derice strength from a false god. The practices themselves are not condemned.*

Lets not forget that Jewish worship includes many of the customs others used to worship their gods - such as animal sacrifice. This is only a problem if done to honor the wrong God.

Answer (score -1):

What about Joseph? He did not read the stars, but dreams with great insight and he predicted the future.

It seems to me a tool can be used for good or bad. If you are trying to predict the future with astrology, Joseph did that with dreams, which is a form of divination. If you are attempting to hurt another or predict the time of death, maybe then it is witchcraft, or pagan. Perhaps this is why laws followed in Lev and Deut. It's always the pagan that ruins it for everyone!

Astrology can simply be a tool that allows for insight into what you are made of. As far as predicting the future, astrology provides nothing more than the equivalent of a weather forecast. There is nothing wicked in knowing if it might rain.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity! Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This answer needs more support. It needs sources and citations, if necessary, to support what you are saying. Otherwise, it just looks like your opinion. Please add more to it to make a truly academic answer. Thank you. References: [Guidelines for writing effective answers](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/guidelines-for-writing-effective-answers) and [What is a well-sourced, dispassionate answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/886/)

Comment: So, the story of Josephs has nothing to do with start and, therefore, nothing to do with astrology.  So, how does this answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

From my best opinion I would say that astrology was indeed created by god for us to use as a tool. This would aid us to know when seasons change and have a way to tell time is passing and navigation. Followers of Satan would also use it in a negative false way that would make it seem to have an evil power. Much like anything else that's a tool. Really depends how you use things cause there is really only two ways. Use it gods way or Satan's way. I would also caution a research or study of it from sources that try to tie in other things like horoscope and tarrot cards cause this is I would think Satan's magic. The only thing I find neat about astrology at the present is it is the oldest form of some type of religion. I don't think god intended it that way. I also wonder what will happen at the end of age as we move to a new age around the year 2300. The way the bible reads it looks like the age of Jesus. So this could be when the world ends as we know it. If that's true Satan (even he knows he can't stop it) wouldn't want anyone to know that. There is also a lot of people in my time that keep spreading fear about different ways the world would end and yet we are still here. Its hard for me to believe that the world gets destroyed. I thought god placed his government here on earth and humans follow his rule? Gods rule is not on this earth as now. Sure he control it allowing or not allowing but his rule isn't here on earth.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: "From my best opinion..." throws up all kind of red flags.  Please consider reading [What makes a good supported answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)